# How to get the whole array from php?

Tags: php, android

I've got an app that displays all the items in a database in a ListView. But i have a problem, i only get the first element in the database.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$dbh = $db->connect(); // here you get the connection

$query = "SELECT *FROM lost_cars";

$result = $dbh->prepare($query);
$result->execute();

if (!empty($result)) {
 // check for empty result
 if ($result->fetchAll() > 0) {


     foreach($dbh->query($query) as $row){
            $car["id"] = $row['id'];
            $car["name"] = $row['name'];

            $response["car"] = array();
            array_push($response["car"], $car);
        // echoing JSON response
        //$response["success"] = 1;
        echo json_encode($response);

        }

    } else {
        // no car found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No car found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // no car found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No car found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

?>

This code is working properly and prints some random values that i previously loaded.

> {"car":[{"id":"11","name":"fgfg"}]}{"car":[{"id":"12","name":"sdf"}]}{"car":[{"id":"14","name":"Cleo"}]}{"car":[{"id":"15","name":"Lola"}]}{"car":[{"id":"16","name":"HOLA"}]}{"car":[{"id":"17","name":"kjlhljh"}]}{"car":[{"id":"18","name":"sdfgsdg"}]}{"car":[{"id":"19","name":"jkl;"}]}{"car":[{"id":"20","name":"asd"}]}{"car":[{"id":"22","name":"asd"}]}{"car":[{"id":"23","name":"sdfsdfd"}]}{"car":[{"id":"24","name":"sdf"}]}{"car":[{"id":"25","name":"kgkgkg"}]}{"car":[{"id":"26","name":"dfgdg"}]}{"car":[{"id":"28","name":"sdf"}]}{"car":[{"id":"29","name":"dfsdf"}]}{"car":[{"id":"30","name":"dfgdfg"}]}{"car":[{"id":"31","name":"sadasd"}]}{"car":[{"id":"32","name":"aca"}]}{"car":[{"id":"34","name":"sdfsdf"}]}{"car":[{"id":"35","name":"sdfsdf"}]}{"car":[{"id":"36","name":"HOLA"}]}{"car":[{"id":"37","name":"qweqwe"}]}{"car":[{"id":"38","name":"df"}]}{"car":[{"id":"39","name":"sda"}]}

Then i successfully parse the result in android, here is a fragment of the JSONParser:

```
 try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
 InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            jObj = new JSONObject(json); //THE PROBLEM

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + 
 e.toString());
        }
```

The problem is when i try to convert the String (json) to a JSONObject. The when i gets passed to the listView to display i only get the first element.

Here is a fragment of code of the ListViewActivity:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URLs.GET_ALL_CARS, "GET", 
 params);
        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Cars: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
           // int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            //if (success == 1) {
                // cars found
                // Getting Array of Products

                cars = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CARS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < cars.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = cars.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    System.out.println(id);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, 
                    String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    carList.add(map);
                }
            //}
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

      // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllCarsActivity.this, carList,
                        R.layout.view_item, new String[]{TAG_ID,
                        TAG_NAME},
                        new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });



    }
```

What could be the problem here? I've been googling for hours with no success, i have not idea of what to do.
I really appreciate your help, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try decoding the json with json_decode then loop through your array of arrays, perhaps nested foreach loops? Sorry I can't be of more help still kinda new myself